# Stop Navbar from rendering in Bootstrap Modals using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I have a ruby app set up that renders a navbar on every page, this is my application.html.erb page

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %> 
    <div class="container">
        <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
            <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
        <% end %>
        <%= yield %>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My home page is set up like this with the modal form before and i have devise handling the new user path.

```
<div class="jumbotron center">
    <h1>Welcome to my app</h1>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
            #do something
        <% else %>

            <p>
                <%= link_to "Log in", new_user_session_path, class: "btn btn-default btn-lg" %>
                <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path   , class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg", :data => {:toggle=>"modal", :target=>"#myModal"} %>
            </p>
        <% end %>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

My problem is that whenever the sign up button is clicked launching the modal the navbar is rendered at the top of the modal box and it ends up looking like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhntZ.png
Anyone know a way to stop the navbar from rendering in these modal pop ups?

Comment: something weird is going on in your app, your headers code is different from your modal code, it shouldn't have showed up there at all. Make sure you have closed all your html tags properly

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if params[:controller]!="login_controller_name" %>
 <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<% end %>
```

could work depending on your setup. This would prevent your header from ever being displayed as long as the view calling it navigated through your login controller. If you don't want the entire controller to avoid displaying the header then whenever you display the popup you should be able to pass some form of parameter in and the same plan would work, you'd just use `params[:supplied_param]` instead.

`if current_page? path` might also work out for you.

Comment: I have devise handling it so I have no controllers created yet. Is there a way in ruby to have a statement like if( path = "new_user_registration_path") {      } else { render 'layouts/header' }

Comment: @RobWilkinson Certainly. I think `if current_page? path` still works. Adding that to answer.

Comment: That worked right there. Thank you, any chance you can say what the advantages and disadvantages of using this method versus the original method you posted?

Comment: While this works, it will prevent you from displaying the actual sign-in page correctly (e.g., when a user visits `/users/sign_up`). For example, if a user has JS disabled, the Sign Up link will take them to the actual page, which will now be missing a header. This method may also load a bunch of HTML into your modal that you don't really need. A better option is to limit what's loaded into your modal using jQuery's `load()` options (which Bootstrap uses internally). See my answer.

Comment: @RobWilkinson there really isn't much of a difference. The `if params[:controller]` is an internal Rails param that is passed along with every call and simply allows you to do controller wide actions. the `if current_page? path` is limited to a single path for more precision control which is probably what you need anyways.

@kardeiz That's actually something in Rails I wasn't aware of. That's interesting. More complicated then I've had need of so far, but obviously useful

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is limit the HTML loaded into your modal; it's currently loading the whole page specified by the link's `href`. You should be able to do this (I've just split it across lines for prettier formatting):

```
<%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path, {
  class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg", 
  data: {
    toggle: "modal",
    target: "#myModal",
    remote: "#{ new_user_registration_path } .container"
  }
} %>
```

Bootstrap modal uses the `href` (or `data-remote` if present) attribute as the first arg to jQuery's `.load()`.

You might want to change the `.container` to some other selector for your sign-in page.

Comment: interesting, if i try your method here, it loads the text and the icons but not the bar if that makes sense. I had it workign with the other method but I would have to make tons of `if( current_page? xxxx)` `elseif( current_page? xxxxx)` `else render 'layouts/header'` This doesnt seem scaleable or useable.

Comment: @RobWilkinson, oh, right, you probably have a `.container` in your header as well. You'll need to use another selector: `.container:last` might work, or you might want to either add a `main` class (or similar) to your main div, or if the Devise form has a unique ID, you could use that.

Comment: Ok that works, but I want to figure out why, let me know if I have the general sense of it. The `<%= link_to` tells ruby its making a link, `class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg"` tells it that its going to have that bootstrap class `toggle: "modal"` tells it to toggle it in a modal format, `target: "#myModal"` tells it what section to toggle on and off, and `remote: "#{ new_user_registration_path } .container:last"` tells it, when you create this path only bring in the last container. Did i get that right?

Comment: @RobWilkinson, Exactly. The `data-remote` overrides `href`, which is what the modal would use otherwise. We need to use `data-remote` here, not `href`, because we are including a URL path and a jQuery selector (for more on this form, see http://api.jquery.com/load/, which is how Bootstrap loads a modal from remote). By having both `href` and `data-remote`, we provide a real link for any users that might have JS disabled.

Comment: the problem now is that cuz its only loading the html once, if you click log in it brings up the proper modal form, but if you back out and hit the sign up button it brings up the log in form instead of the sign up form.

Comment: Its only loading the new data when you hit the button then just changing `display: none` when you back out and then changing it to visible again even if you opening the other link. Is there a way I can  force it to reload every time. I've pushed it to heroku if you'd like to see what I'm talking about http://www.rw-pinteresting.herokuapp.com/

Comment: In the example code you provide, the login link isn't loaded in a modal. If you want to have it in a modal, you might define a second modal block on your page. Your Heroku URL says "No such app".